# Servlet cancel post request in refresh

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following:

- JSP page submits a request to a Servlet to add a new customer
- Servlet uses some Action class
- redirect to some other Jsp page

Here is the source code.

**new_customer.jsp:**

```
<form action="/NewCustomerServlet" method="post">

  <input type="test" name="company_name" />
  <input type="submit" name="save_button" value="Save"/>

</form>
```

**NewCustomerServlet:**

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, response) throws ServletException, IOException {
if(request.getParameter("save_button") != null){
    Customer customer;
    try {
        customer = action.createCustomer(request, response);
        request.setAttribute(Const.CUSTOMER, customer);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp?v=v_cst");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return;
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        request.setAttribute(Const.ERR_MSG_ATTR_NAME, "Failed to insert new customer: " +
                             e.getMessage());
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("CRM/index.jsp?v=n_cst");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        return;
    }    
}
```

**index.jsp**:

```
<%
    if(request.getParameter("v").equals("v_cst")) {%>
        <jsp:include page="customer/view_customer.jsp"></jsp:include>
<%} %>
```

**view_customer.jsp**:

```
<%
    Customer customer = (Customer)request.getAttribute(Const.CUSTOMER);

    String customerId = "";
    String name = "";
    String phone = "";
    String website = "";
    String address = "";

    if(customer != null){

        customerId = customer.getCustomerId();
        name = customer.getName();
        phone = customer.getPhone();
        website = customer.getWebsite();
        address = customer.getAddress();
    }
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Customer ID</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customer_id" value="<%=customerId %>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="javascript:searchCustomer"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label name="search_customer_err_msg" value="" style="color: red;"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Customer Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customer_name"  value="<%= name%>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Customer website</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customer_website" value="<%= website%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Customer phone</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customer_phone" value="<%= phone%>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Customer Address</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="customer_address" value="<%= address%>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

After adding a new customer from the page new_customer.jsp, and viewing the page view_customer.jsp in the browser, if I refresh the page (from the page where I see the view_customer.jsp) it will submit the data again to the servlet and add a new customer and I will see the same data with a new customer id.

Maybe I should mention also that i see in the browser address bar, the URL of the `NewCustomerServlet` and not of the index page.

Anyone knows what I missed here to cancel the post again in refresh?

** Maybe i forgot to mention that also the new_customer.jsp is also included in the index.jsp page, maybe this could be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: You are viewing the data on view_customer.jsp page, and there is only one button (search).Then how its submitting the new_customer.jsp page submit button.That new_customer.jsp is a separate page or its included with any other page ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you can notice in the index.jsp code i include the view_customer page

Comment: Maybe i forgot to mention that also the new_customer.jsp is also included in the index.jsp page, maybe this could be the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: Yes , just separate the new_customer.jsp from index.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You do not redirect to the view, you just forward to the corresponding JSP server-side, so the browser won't get notified of a new URL.

Instead of using a `RequestDispatcher` you must build a redirect URL and perform [`HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29). That way your servlet sends an HTTP Redirect back to the client, which will call the corresponding URL and corresspondingly change the address bar.

And you probably do not want to redirect to the JSP itself, but to another controller:

In `NewCustomerServlet`:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    customer = action.createCustomer(request, response);
    response.sendRedirect("ShowCustomer?customerId=" + customer.getCustomerId());
    ...
```

And the `ShowCustomerServlet` might look like this:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // get customer by HTTP Request Parameter 'customerId'
    customer = action.getCustomer(request, response);

    // set attribute and forward to JSP
    request.setAttribute(Const.CUSTOMER, customer);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("showCustomer.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to use the dispatcher so i can pass an object with the request as attribute! if i use send redirect i can 't do it!

Comment: @Marwan Jaber: Exactly, that's why you might need another controller. Fact is, that in case of a redirect you loose the 'request context'. So if you want to redirect you need a mecahnism to transfer the state, in my example it's the parameter `customerId`.

Comment: Tried this also, but didn't work! when you refresh the browser, the browser sends the same previous request with the same parameters including the action assigned, i see the solution as either the browser forgets the previous action or the servlet identifies if the request was sent from a refresh and ignores it. in .net for example you can set a parameter that cancels the post back and this cancels the resubmit. thank you for your answer but unfortunately it didn't work niether

Comment: @Marwan Jaber: It will work, but it might require more changes than you think of. A `sendRedirect` will modify the browser URL, check the Post/Redirect/Get pattern on e.g. Wikipedia for further details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get